# FileInputStream can't find file on android studio

Tags: java, android

"""

```
package com.example.pillappreal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ArrayList<Drug> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static MyAdapter myAdapter;
    public static ListView listView;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/root/SD/Download/drugs.txt";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        load();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter((MyAdapter) myAdapter);
    }

    public void addNewDrugButton(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewDrugActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void addNewDrug(Drug drug) throws IOException {
        list.add(drug);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        save();
    }

    public void save() {
        for(Drug drug : list) {
            String text = storeDrug(drug);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;

            try {
                fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(text.getBytes());

                Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to" + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void load()   {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        list.clear();
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String text;

            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(text).append("\n");
            }

            Drug drug = drugBuilder(text);
            list.add(drug);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String storeDrug(Drug drug) {
        String name = drug.getName();
        int dose = drug.getDose();
        String frequency = drug.getFrequency();
        frequency.replace(" ", "@");
        String checkBoxId = drug.getCheckBoxId();
        boolean checked = drug.getChecked();
        String returnS = name + " " + dose + " " + frequency + " " + checkBoxId + " " + checked;
        return returnS;
    }

    public Drug drugBuilder(String text) {
        Drug drug = null;
        String[] arr = text.split(" " , 0);
        String name = arr[0];
        int dose = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        String frequency = arr[2];
        String checkBoxId = arr[3];
        boolean checked;
        if (arr[4].contains("true")) {
            checked = true;
        } else {
            checked = false;
        }
        drug.setName(name);
        drug.setDose(dose);
        drug.setFrequency(frequency);
        drug.setCheckBoxId(checkBoxId);
        drug.setChecked(checked);

        return drug;
    }


}
```

"""
Stack Trace:

```
2022-04-26 09:52:04.420 3962-3962/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pillappreal, PID: 3962
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pillappreal/com.example.pillappreal.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /root/SD/Download/drugs.txt contains a path separator
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449 undefined)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601 undefined)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85 undefined)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135 undefined)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95 undefined)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066 undefined)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106 undefined)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223 undefined)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592 undefined)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947 undefined)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /root/SD/Download/drugs.txt contains a path separator
   at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2867 undefined)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:635 undefined)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:216 undefined)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:216 undefined)
   at com.example.pillappreal.MainActivity.load(MainActivity.java:86 undefined)
   at com.example.pillappreal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38 undefined)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994 undefined)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978 undefined)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309 undefined)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422 undefined)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601 undefined) 
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85 undefined) 
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135 undefined) 
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95 undefined) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066 undefined) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106 undefined) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223 undefined) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656 undefined) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592 undefined) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947 undefined)
```

I have a project here that is supposed to save the contents of an arraylist of custom objects as lines on a text file. storeDrug() takes the fields from a drug object and converts it into a line of text that is supposed to be saved to a text file in save(). load() is supposed to read each line in the file and use buildDrug() to turn each line into a drug object to then populate the arraylist with those objects. I am getting a nullpointerexception when I call load. I think this has something to do with the method being unable to find the file. The file is copied onto the file system of the emulated android device.

Comment: If an app can write a file than it can certainly read the file later.

Comment: `The file is copied onto the file system of the emulated android device.`? Who is copying a file? You were creating one you said.

Comment: `I am getting a nullpointerexception when I call load.` Post the stacktrace. It will tell you exactly which pointer is null.

Comment: posted. lmk if it's formatted correctly i threw it into a stack trace formatter.

Comment: This is your problem: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /root/SD/Download/drugs.txt contains a path separator` And you have this error already wirh save(). Why didnt you tell? Now try to realize what the error means. Then tell us.

Comment: `/root/SD/Download` That is a path that will not exist on any Android device by the way.

Comment: Before I had the same problem with just /SD/Download and with just the file name

Comment: I changed the fis to = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME)) which fixed the crashing issue but the outcome is not what it should be yet, which is to say the file should have a base test text in it to test if it is actually reading that text. It is not.